# How to retrieve data from XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

first time poster here.

I have tried very hard to find a solution to my problem, both with my own intellect and other resources, but it has all been to no avail.

So, I have a temp table structure as such:

```
CREATE TABLE #ErrorTable
(
    SessionId VARCHAR(100),
    errorXml XML
)
```

It can be assumed that another query will successfully insert the session id and XML, with multiple entries, which has a structure in the likes of:

```
<Message>
  <Header>
    <To>test</To>
    <From>test</From>
    <MessageID>k3lkjasd</MessageID>
    <RelatesToMessageID>6hu</RelatesToMessageID>
    <SentTime>2014-02-28T15:09:29.2921688-05:00</SentTime>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <Error>
      <Code>600</Code>
      <DescriptionCode>14</DescriptionCode>
      <Description>Invalid Login Id</Description>
    </Error>
  </Body>
</Message>
```

My problem is trying to retrieve all of the the Description values from the Error node. I have tried the following queries:

```
SELECT n.l.value('DescriptionCode[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS ErrorDescription
FROM #ErrorTable
CROSS APPLY errorXml.nodes('/Message/Body/Error') n(l)

SELECT errorXml.value(N'(/Message/Body/Error/DescriptionCode/node())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ErrorDescription FROM #ErrorTable
```

Neither of those queries work.

Any information or help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: **How** don't they work? Both those queries are valid.

Comment: @podiluska the first query returns nothing at all, while the second one returns all null values. The table has records, so I don't see why it would return all null values.

Comment: Neither do I. I just created a test table, with that value in it, and both your queries returned the 14 value.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?:

```
SELECT errorXml.value('(/Message/Body/Error/Description)[1]', 'varchar(max)') FROM #ErrorTable
```